# How to upload file using java ?

Tags: java, liferay, fileinputstream

Hello i m trying to upload file using java file.. but i don't get it.. i get file size=0 i'm providing here my java code. tell me why i cant upload on particular folder. i want to store my file in particular folder. i am trying to get file size, file name but i got the null value where am i wrong please tell me.

```
public void updateTesti(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException
{
    //image upload logic
    String folder_for_upload =(getPortletContext().getRealPath("/"));
    //String folder=actionRequest.getParameter("uploadfolder");
    realPath=getPortletContext().getRealPath("/");  

    logger.info("RealPath is" + realPath);
    logger.info("Folder is :" + folder_for_upload);
    try
    {
        logger.info("Admin is try to upload");

        UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);

        if (uploadRequest.getSize("fileName") == 0) {
            SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, "error");
        }
        String sourceFileName = uploadRequest.getFileName("fileName");
        File uploadedFile = uploadRequest.getFile("fileName");
        System.out.println("Size of uploaded file: " + uploadRequest.getSize("fileName"));

        logger.info("Uploded file name is: " + uploadRequest.getFileName("fileName"));                  
        String destiFolder=("/home/ubuntu/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/imageUpload-portlet/image");
        String newsourcefilename = (uploadRequest.getFileName("fileName"));
        File  newFile = new File(destiFolder +"/"+ newsourcefilename);

        logger.info("New file name: " + newFile.getName());
        logger.info("New file path: " + newFile.getPath());

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uploadRequest.getFileAsStream("fileName"));

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        byte[] bytes_ = FileUtil.getBytes(in);
        int i = fis.read(bytes_);
        while (i != -1) {
            fos.write(bytes_, 0, i);
            i = fis.read(bytes_);
        }
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
        Float size = (float) newFile.length();

        System.out.println("file size bytes:" + size);
        System.out.println("file size Mb:" + size / 1048576);

        logger.info("File created: " + newFile.getName());
        SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "success");

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "error");
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
        e.printStackTrace();
        SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "error");
    }
    catch (IOException e1)
    {
        System.out.println("Error Reading The File.");
        SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "error");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you tagged this as "liferay".  I am to assume this is a Portlet?  Can you provide the output of all the System.out.println() statements?

Comment: can you provide your jsp code

Comment: Same issue here. I'm guessing this has something to do with the filename. I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @CodeChimp what should i do if the mentioned folder is not available, and i want portlet creates a folder itself and upload a file inside

Comment: @Akash You should really start a new question and not try to hijack someone else's.  But, to answer your question, you should code your portlet in such a way that checks if the file is there, and if it is not direct the user to an upload form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this to upload small files < 1kb

```
File f2 = uploadRequest.getFile("fileupload", true);
```

They are stored in memory only. I have it in my catch statement incase I get a null pointer - or incase my original file (f1.length) == 0

Answer (score 0):

I have executed your code.It is working as per expectation.There might be something wrong in your jsp page.I am not sure but might be your name attribute is not same as the one which you are using in `processAction`(assuming that you are using portlet).Parameter is case sensitive,so check it again.

You will find more on below link.It has good explanation in file upload.

http://www.codeyouneed.com/liferay-portlet-file-upload-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

I went through a file upload code, and when i implement that in my local system what i got is, portlet is saving the file i upload in `tomcat/webbapp/abc_portlet_project` location, what i dont understand is from where portlet found

> String folder = getInitParameter("uploadFolder");
>
> ```
>                String realPath = getPortletContext().getRealPath("/");
>
>                System.out.println("RealPath" + realPath +"\\" + folder); try {
> ```
>
> UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest =
>   PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
>   System.out.println("Size: "+uploadRequest.getSize("fileName"));
>
> if (uploadRequest.getSize("fileName")==0)
>   {SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, "error");}
>
> String sourceFileName = uploadRequest.getFileName("fileName"); File
>   file = uploadRequest.getFile("fileName");
>
> System.out.println("Nome file:" +
>   uploadRequest.getFileName("fileName")); File newFolder = null;
>   newFolder = new File(realPath +"\" + folder);
>   if(!newFolder.exists()){ newFolder.mkdir(); }
>                File newfile = null;
>                  newfile = new File(newFolder.getAbsoluteFile()+"\"+sourceFileName);
>                  System.out.println("New file name: " + newfile.getName());
>                  System.out.println("New file path: " + newfile.getPath());
>
> InputStream in = new
>   BufferedInputStream(uploadRequest.getFileAsStream("fileName"));
>   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); FileOutputStream fos
>   = new FileOutputStream(newfile);

Comment: I can't see any answer here, maybe you would like to edit that post?